# Extracting icons with imagemagick creates black stripes on transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

For a project of mine I'm fetching websites favicons and storing them to be displayed in a website. Sounds pretty trivial, but I have one strange issue. Almost all icons come in a .ico format, which is not very web friendly. Some icons also have different sizes in them.
I'm using Imagemagick to convert them to PNG and extract only the 16x16 icon.

I'm using the following command line for this:

```
convert source.ico -geometry 16x16 -alpha on -background none -flatten out.png
```

Unfortunately on some icons this creates some nasty horizontal black stripes in the transparent areas. Here is an example:

This is the original icon:

http://g.etfv.co/http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/

This is the result:

http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/1463/65407408.png

Here it is again embedded here:

[image]

What could be wrong here? My ImageMagick is version 6.5.4-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Imagemagick installation: I tried your command with your .ico file with version 6.6.0-1 and it created the png file correctly

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-03 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suitable package for CentOS 6? I cannot find one... I can find only for CentOS 5 and they do not work on 6.

Comment: OK I found a way, using the remi repo. The package there is called ImageMagick-last.